# Combine Javascript on blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Can anybody here provide me some imformation on how I can combine js files? I searched StackOverflow and Google but couldn't find what I need. I am working on Blogger and I have some scripts like this included:

```
<script src='http://yourjavascript.com/5334401280/content-slider.js'/>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
featuredcontentslider.init({
id: "slider1", //id of main slider DIV
contentsource: ["inline", ""], //Valid values: ["inline", ""] or ["ajax", "path_to_file"]
toc: "#increment", //Valid values: "#increment", "markup", ["label1", "label2", etc]
nextprev: ["Προηγούμενο", "Επόμενο"], //labels for "prev" and "next" links. Set to "" to hide.
enablefade: [true, 0.5], //[true/false, fadedegree]
autorotate: [true, 7500], //[true/false, pausetime]
onChange: function(previndex, curindex){ //event handler fired whenever script changes slide
//previndex holds index of last slide viewed b4 current (1=1st slide, 2nd=2nd etc)
//curindex holds index of currently shown slide (1=1st slide, 2nd=2nd etc)
}
})
//]]>
</script>
```

Can I combine them and reduce HTML requests?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a build tool like GruntJS to combine and minify your code into one file.

http://gruntjs.com/

If you are developing in Linux or MacOS you could use the cat command in the terminal:

```
cat file1.js file2.js ... fileN.js > output.js
```

Remember order is important. Combine them in the order you have them in your HTML file. Now you will have a file called output.js that has all your JavaScript inside. Then just use this file in your HTML.

```
<script src="output.js"></script>
```

Comment: I feel like using `cat file1.js file2.js ... fileN.js` would just be asking for namespace conflicts

Comment: If the scripts were loaded into the browser already it is no different then if you combine them into one file versus N separate script tags.

Comment: what if i dont use linux or mac os? thanks for the answers by the way. :)

Comment: I would recommend going with a build tool :) there are many of them out there. The build tool I choose is Grunt. You need to have NodeJS/NPM installed on your machine to use grunt.

I am not sure what the windows commands are to merge files. I don't develop in windows.